# Typescript classes converted back to objects after map, filter, find etc

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

If you have an array of class instances in TS and for instance perform a find on the array and assign the result to a new variable, the new variable is no longer an instance of the class, it's just a plain object. This means you then have to create a new instance of the class from the object before you can call any class methods.

Is this something that is intended, if so why?

Edit - or am I doing something wrong?

`let someArray = [anInstance, anInstance, anInstance...];`

`let myFoundInstance = someArray.find(el => el.thing === 'something');`

myFoundInstance is actually an object at this point, and you can't call any class methods on it until you create a new instance from it

Comment: Why do you say it's no longer an instance?

Comment: At runtime you can no longer call class methods, unless you make a new instance from the object. Seems odd

Comment: That's not true though. Check this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20log()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.id)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20found%20%3D%20arr.find(el%20%3D%3E%20el.id%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afound.log()%3B

Comment: Can you give a real working example that demonstrates your problem? I gave a complete working example answer which doesn't exhibit your described problem.

Comment: @Alex You might want to vote to close as "not reproducible" instead of answering :-)

Answer (score 0):

This small test program appears to work fine, which satisfies what you're describing:

```js
class A {
  str: string;
  constructor(value: string) {
    this.str = value;
  }
  print = () => {
    console.log(`i am ${this.str}`);
  }
}

const array: A[] = [new A("one"), new A("two")];

const one = array.find(it => it.str === "one");
array[0].print();
one!.print();
```

Which produces the expected output from invoking the `print` function on both instances

```
i am one
i am one
```